# How to create a function that changes the color of a single line from black to grey to white?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have coded a cube using canvas and the `<script>` tag. I would like to create a function that changes the color of a single line from black to grey to white within a given timeframe.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctxfii = c.getContext("2d");
ctxfii.beginPath();
ctxfii.moveTo(700, 415);
ctxfii.lineTo(700, 515);
ctxfii.lineWidth = 1;
ctxfii.strokeStyle = "black";
ctxfii.stroke();  

var colorChange = ctxfii;
function colorChange () {
    window.setInterval(10);
    document.getElementById("myCanvas").strokeStyle = "grey"
};
```

Nothing comes up the whole canvas appears blank.

Answer (score 1):

I'm animating the value for strokeStyle from black `rgb(0,0,0)` to white `rgb(255,255,255)`. In order to make it go from black to grey to white back to grey and black again I'm using `Math.abs(Math.sin(H)) * 255;`

Instead of using `setInterval` I'm using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Also I'm translating the context because I wanted to see the line, but you can remove this part.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c.width = 400;
c.height = 400;
var ctxfii = c.getContext("2d");

// I'm translating the context because I want to see the line;
ctxfii.translate(-600,-400)

ctxfii.strokeStyle = "black";

drawLine();

let H = 0;
function colorChange () {
    requestAnimationFrame(colorChange);
    H+= .01;
    let h = Math.abs(Math.sin(H)) * 255;
    //delete everithing on the canvas
    ctxfii.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height)
    // I'm animating the strokeStyle from black: rgb(0,0,0) to white: rgb(255,255,255)
    ctxfii.strokeStyle = `rgb(${h},${h},${h})`;
    //redraw the line:
    drawLine();
};

colorChange()

// a function to draw the line; I'll need this function more than once
function drawLine(){
    ctxfii.beginPath();
    ctxfii.moveTo(700, 415);
    ctxfii.lineTo(700, 515);
    ctxfii.lineWidth = 1;

    ctxfii.stroke();  
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;background:skyblue;}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```